# Mysql partitioning and joins

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

Sorry if this is a stupid question but new to this so need some help to understand a couple of things. Im currently upgrading mysql to 5.1 so I can use partitions in mysql. My question is if I partition a table, would a partitioned table, including the pruning process, still work on a quering using a join or is partitioning optimal if your just quering the table that has the partitions?

**EDIT**

Here is an example query:

```
SELECT event.*,site.* FROM event INNER JOIN site ON event.siteid = site.id
WHERE event.eventdate >= [somedate] AND event.eventdate <= [somedate]
AND event.siteid = [siteid]
```

And I have partitions setup on the events table using the eventdate field. Would mysql still be able to use the partitions on the events table including the pruning process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partioned tables can be used in joins.

Tweak the `where` clause to include one partition only to get the best performance.
e.g. if you partition by year, you can do a join like:

```
select * from a
inner join partioned_table p on (p.id = a.id)
where p.year = '2011';
```

This query will work with and without the where clause, but with the where clause it will be much faster because you are only accessing one partition.
If you access more partitions, MySQL has to use a temporary table to stitch the partitions together before it can do the join.
This kind of defeats the purpose of partitions.

Comment: What do you mean by include one partition? Is there an example you are referring to? What if the query has dates that belong in multiple partitions? I updated my original post with an example query

Comment: so I guess I should break the table up by year then because if I do by month-year it would increase the chance of having to scan multiple partitions correct?

Comment: @John, exactly if you want performance you should split your partitions so you almost never query from more than one partition. If you don't mix months than partitioning by month is fine of course, it depends.

Comment: They might search by a start and end date that goes between 2 different months for example the last 30 days up till now crosses over may and june. The only problem is there could be a million rows for 1 year so instead of searching 3 million they are searching 1 million. Still a lot of rows to search. That is why I thought it would be better to do it by month/year instead of year

Comment: Searching 2 partitions is better than 12 partitions, I suggest you experiment. Going though 1 partition is always best, but I guess 2 partitions of 100,000 + 100,000 rows is faster than going though 1 partition of a million rows.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question well, but the partitioning should not affect the way your joins work.  It just affects the way the data is stored. MySQL engine will take care of knowing where to fetch the data, so in reality you should keep your joins just the way you have them.  Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE members (
    firstname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(35),
    joined DATE NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE( YEAR(joined) ) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1960),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1970),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (1980),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (1990),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);

select a.* 
from members a, subscriptions b 
where a.email = b.email and b.generation='X' 
  and a.joined between '1980-01-01' and now()
```

Let me know if that makes sense!
Marcelo

Comment: That makes sense. My question is though how does partitions handle indexes? In your query your joining the tables by email, but in your create statement you do not have any indexes. So how does that work for optimization? Can you not have any indexes on a partitioned table?

Comment: @John, yup, you can with no problems! There is thread with your question in the mysql forum. Let me put it [http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?106,202130,202140#msg-202140] (here).According to the thread, "If you have a table partitioned by month, and create an index on that table, it will effectively be partitioned by month as well."

Comment: so if I had an index on email in your members table it wouldnt cause any issues with the partition? Also what if I have a primary auto incremented key in the events table? Will this affect partitioning?